# Trying to run a postgres script as another user from a Unit file, but variable is not being passed

Tags: shell-script, centos, environment-variables, docker, systemd-unit

I have a docker container, and `-e DEV_ENV` is defined with the docker run command, and this the unit file I built to run a script...

```
[Unit]
Description=Script that creates environement users and databases.
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/su - postgres -c 'export DEV_ENV=$0; /usr/local/bin/psql.sh' "$DEV_ENV"
TimeoutStartSec=100

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I'm trying to run the following script...

```
#!/bin/bash
while [[ $(systemctl status postgresql.service | awk '/Active/sub("\\(","")  { print $3 }' | awk 'sub("\\)","")' ) != "running" ]]
do echo "Waiting on service to come up.";done

for i in ${DEV_ENV[*]};do EX=$(psql -lt | cut -d\| -f1 | grep ${i,,})
echo "Creating ${i}"
if [[ ! ${EX} ]];then
        psql -c "CREATE DATABASE ${i};"
        psql -c "CREATE USER $i WITH PASSWORD '${i}'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $i TO ${i};"
fi;done
```

I know the script runs, I put in checks at beginning and end of the script.
Unfortunately the Unit file fails because the `$DEV_ENV` variable is not being passed.

I can run the following manually and it works.

```
/usr/bin/su - postgres -c 'export DEV_ENV=$0; /usr/local/bin/psql.sh' "$DEV_ENV"
```

How do I properly pass the environment variable to the postgres shell?

Comment: Is the command in the unit file even being executed in an environment where the `DEV_ENV` variable has a meaningful value?

Comment: @Kusalananda I'm not sure what you are asking. 
The variable has a value, it's an Environment variable, but the value is not being passed to the postgres shell via the command.

Comment: Where do you define this environment variable?

Comment: This is a docker container it is defined in the Dockerfile and then additionally defined in the **docker run -d -e DEV_ENV='myapi1 myapi2'** ....command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible to use environment variables with Unit files when you are trying to run a script as another user.
Unit file permissions were root:root and the script was being run as postgres:postgres.

I even tried using an EnvironmentFile in the Unit file, this also failed in the container.
Could be because I am using a SystemD replacement from gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement. Maybe something else, either way the service was failing.

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/dockerenv
```

In the end I ended up adding an ExecStartPost line to the postgresql.service file.

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c /usr/local/bin/psql.sh
```

The dockerenv file was being created on boot with a startup script using the following...

```
#Create EnvironmentFile for postgres user when running psql.sh
echo "DEV_ENV=\"${DEV_ENV}\"
PUID=${PUID}
GUID=${GUID}" > /etc/sysconfig/dockerenv
```

Then the psql.sh script retrieves the variable values in there when it runs.

```
#!/bin/bash
date
POS_ENV=$(cat /etc/sysconfig/dockerenv | awk -F= '/DEV_ENV/ { print $2 }' | awk 'gsub("\"","")') 
while [[ $(systemctl status postgresql.service | awk '/Active/sub("\\(","")  { print $3 }' | awk 'sub("\\)","")' ) != "running" ]]
do echo "Waiting on service to come up.";done

for i in ${POS_ENV[*]};do EX=$(psql -lt | cut -d\| -f1 | grep ${i,,})
echo "Creating ${i}"
if [[ ! ${EX} ]];then
        psql -c "CREATE DATABASE ${i};"
        psql -c "CREATE USER $i WITH PASSWORD '${i}'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $i TO ${i};"
fi;done
```